# Is this series well known?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I recently encountered the following function

$$
f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^{n^2}}{n^2!}.
$$

It seems familiar, though I cannot remember where I might have seen it before. I would like to know in what text, if any, it has been studied. Above all, I would like to know its asymptotic properties (how fast it grows) as $t$ tends to infinity ($t$ real and positive).

Thanks,

G.

Comment: Related to (integral of) the theta function $\theta(0,\tau)$, http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thetafunktion.

Comment: As with the exponential series, for large $t$ the biggest terms are when $n\approx t$.  At this point about one in every $2t$ terms of the exponential series are present, and vary on approximately that scale, so we should have $f(t)\sim c(t)e^t/t$ where $c(t)$ is bounded. I think it will wriggle between two limits indefinitely.

Comment: @Dirk: How it is related to the integral of theta-function? Where will $(n^2)!$ in the denominator will come from?

Comment: Well, its only loosely related.  Your f is almost the integral of $\sum t^{n^2}$…

Comment: @Brendan McKey: $n$-th term becomes the biggest when $t\sim n^2$.

Comment: @Dirk: Why almost? Is $(n^2)!$ "almost" $n^2$?

Comment: Oops,  totally missed that $!$…

Comment: @Alexandre: you are right.  I should have written $f(t)\sim c(t)e^t/\sqrt t$.  I'll submit an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a slice of the taylor series for $\exp(t)$.  The terms that dominate are those near $n=t^{1/2}$.  Using Stirling's approximation, as $t\to\infty$ with $q$ more or less bounded, we have
$$\frac{t^{(t^{1/2}+q)^2}}{(t^{1/2}+q)^2)!} = \frac{e^{t-2q^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} (1 + O(q^3/t)).$$
So $$f(t) \sim \frac{e^t}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}c(t),$$ where
$$c(t) = \sum_q e^{-2q^2},$$
with the sum over all $q$ for which $t^{1/2}+q$ is integer.

It is clear that $c(t)$ depends only on the fractional part of $t^{1/2}$.  It is nice curve that oscillates between 1.2353 (when $t^{1/2}$ is midway between two integers) and 1.2679 (when $t^{1/2}$ is an integer).